# Both jQuery and JavaScript returns blank text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am coding a website with bootstrap. I have a modal, it contains a tetxtbox and a button. I want when i click the button, an alert box gives me the textbox value. But there is a problem that i can not solve. Alert box shows nothing.

**Like this:**

[image]

**My codes and tries:**

**index.html**

```
<div class="form-inline" id="b"> 
     <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="textbox" placeholder="something">
     <button type="button" id="button1" class="btn btn-info">Button</button>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
$("#button1").click(function(){     
   var x = $("#textbox").val();
   alert(x);            
});
```

**I also tried this way in js file:**

```
$("#button1").click(function(){     
   var x = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
   alert(x);            
});
```

Why can't I get the value? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/ark9fjxs/ (You're not expecting to see the placeholder value, are you?)

Comment: Please provide demo that replicates problem

Comment: What happens if you put an actual value on the input? There isn't one in your example code.

Comment: i am not expecting to see placeholder @Juhana and yes if my codes are tried like in my question, they are working. like Juhana's fiddle. but in whole project, they are not working. May bootstrap caused this? or being in a modal? i can not understand

Comment: @isherwood if i put an actual value, i see same alert box.

Comment: do you see any error in console

Comment: Probably something wrong in your passing of the value to modal element. Without code that replicates problem all you will get is a bunch of blind guesses for answers

Answer (score 1):

**Check the demo is this the thing you were looking for**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/bn2crc28/
```

html

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p><input type='text' id="textbox"/>
              <a href="#" id="test" role="button" class="btn btn-default popover-test" title="" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title">button</a> </p>


          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>

      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#test').on('click',function(){
    alert($('#textbox').val());

});
```

note:include jquery and bootstrap as shown in demo